# How do I enable the NewRelic Python agent?

Tags: python, newrelic

While trying to test my NewRelic configuration using `newrelic-admin validate-config newrelic.ini` as recommended by https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/testing-the-python-agent, I received the following error:

```
WARNING - The Python Agent is not enabled.

ERROR - Unable to register application for test, connection could not be established within 30.0 seconds.
```

What does the warning mean, and how do I enable the agent? Why does the agent need to be enabled to validate the config?

Comment: did you set NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT and NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that one of the `developer_mode` or `monitor_mode` configuration options must be set to `true` in your configuration file to "enable" the agent.

However, as it looks like the config validator actually spins up the agent using your configuration under a test app called "Python Agent Test" and tries to report to NewRelic, setting `developer_mode` to `true` enables the agent but still causes the tests to fail. Actually, it looks like the tests failing is a bug, as the error message is `ERROR - Unexpected exception when attempting to harvest the metric data and send it to the data collector. Please report this problem to New Relic support for further investigation.`, and the traceback shows a failed assertion in `newrelic.core.data_collector.send_request`.

Setting `monitor_mode = true` in the configuration file should successfully enable the agent and cause the tests to pass, with data for the `PythonAgentTest` application appearing in the NewRelic dashboard.